# making movable menu items in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Making movable menu items in html,
I have four menu items arranged in right corner of my site vertically one below the other like

```
Home
Services
Contact 
About
```

Now i need On click of second element(services) the second element has come to top and first element(home) has to push down, similarly click on third element has to come to top and first has to push down .
Any help and any reference links Thanks  ?

Comment: You could do this purely in CSS if you used flexbox, using the `order` property. Otherwise, it will be a jQuery solution most likely to shuffle the nodes around.

We need way more details, though, what is your menu markup like?

Comment: You are outrightly asking how to implement, as a tutorial. First try out yourself, then update your question here with the code you have tried and the problem you are facing

Comment: Also, you need to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve. Should the menu items slide smoothly around, or can they jump instantly?

Comment: Here is a quick example of having them jump straight to the top whenever you click them: http://jsfiddle.net/a8fm184n/

Comment: @charankumar I added that as an answer for you to accept, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could have the options jump straight to the top when you click them:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    $(event.target).prependTo('#menu');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/a8fm184n/)