# making movable items in html and the menu items slide smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is the extension of the following question
[making movable menu items in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480660/making-movable-menu-items-in-html)

here I am using the navigation menu

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

the problem here is it is not retrieving the values after page refresh for a static page it is working fine. The menu items has to slide smoothly

Any help thanks ?

Comment: You're probably looking for jQuery cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery cookie](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js) to store order of `li`.

See Sample : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hcposhy/)**

```
$(function () {
    if ($.cookie('menuOrder') != null) {
        var menuOrder = $.cookie('menuOrder').split(',');
        var li = $('#menu li');
        li.detach().sort(function (a, b) {
            return (menuOrder.indexOf($(a).text()) > menuOrder.indexOf($(b).text()));
        });
        $('#menu').append(li);
    }
    $('#menu ').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
        $(event.target).prependTo('#menu ');
        $.cookie('menuOrder', $('#menu li ').map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        })
            .get()
            .join());
    });

});
```